# How to use Prism with Spring.net

Tags: prism, spring.net

I am currently trying to complete [this tutorial](http://blogs.infosupport.com/using-spring-net-as-ioc-container-for-composite-wpf/) to get Prism to work with Spring.net.

After referencing Prism4 and Spring.Net through NuGet (or manualy referencing the assemblies), setting up a bootstrapper and running the application I get a "File or Assembly "System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, ..." FileNotFoundException.

I am succesfully using Prism and Spring.Net in seperate projects. Above exception only occours in a project where Prism AND Spring.net is referenced. Spring.net is not even used in code or app.config. Searching various sites I could not find any informations on version issues or similar problems.

```
namespace PrismSpringSandbox {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für "App.xaml"
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
            bootstrapper.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

The Exception occours on "bootstrapper.Run()".

```
namespace HelloWorld {
    public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper {
        protected override DependencyObject CreateShell() {
            Shell1 shell = new Shell1();
            shell.Activate();
            RegionManager.UpdateRegions();
            shell.Show();

            return shell;
        }

        protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog() {

            DirectoryModuleCatalog catalog = new DirectoryModuleCatalog{ModulePath = @".\"};

            //ModuleCatalog catalog =
            //    new     ModuleCatalog().AddModule(typeof(HelloWorldModule.HelloWorldModule)).AddModule(
            //        typeof(SecondaryModule.SecondaryModule));

            return catalog;
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe someone knows a solution for this problem when trying to use current Prism with current Spring.Net versions.

Comment: Is your project set to be .Net framework 4.0 CF ?

Comment: @Piu:Project is using 4.0 full profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it!

Problem was a reference to unity while referncing spring.net at the same time.